# Inserting a row break in dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table rendered by Apex code in salesfoce.

```html
<div id="wrap" style=""><fieldset style="border: none;"><table role="presentation" style="">
 <tbody><tr>
    <td>
<input type="radio"value="Casual"><label for="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id112:0"> CASUAL</label></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" value="BUSINESS CASUAL"><label for="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id112:1"> BUSINESS CASUAL</label></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" value="Semi-Formal"><label for="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id112:2"> SEMI-FORMAL</label></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" value="Formal"><label for="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id112:3"> FORMAL</label></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" value="Costume"><label for="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id112:4"> COSTUME</label></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" value="Other"><label for="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id112:5"> OTHER</label></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table></fieldset>
            </div>
```

I need to break the row after third label . which means three inputs/labels in one row. 
I can use jQuery. I have tried everything like injecting closing `</tr>` tag after third input via innerHTML etc . But nothing seems to work .

Comment: insert `<br />` using javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to manipulate the DOM a little bit,

```
$('<tr>').append($('tr td:gt(2)')).appendTo('tbody');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zjwkyxLo/)

Comment: my answer will not work i think but you are ultimate.+1

Comment: Awesome . It worked . There could be more tables/tr on page so i added #wrap selector with tbody to limit it to that div only. is it feasible ?
http://jsfiddle.net/zjwkyxLo/1/

Comment: Yeah, that's right.. I just written that code in a rush.. Yes you can use it.. :) And by the way.. Glad to help..

Comment: Thanks :). Can you please tell why the </tr> couldn't get injected via innerHTML neither via pure js or jquery ?

Comment: I'm trying to apply your answer to my case but I couldn't, so I posted a new question, do you think that you can answer it and save me? ► https://stackoverflow.com/q/63194846/3298930 .