# Generate table row break conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a `<table>` with two cells that I want to display horizontally if device is computer or vertically if it's mobile. I borrowed a JS function to detect mobile from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/3298930 that works great.

My horizontal table looks like this (actually, it's more complicated, but I want to make it simple) :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <video>s </td>
    <td> description and capture data </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In order to make it vertical I only need to insert two tags :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <video>s </td>
  </tr> ◄────────────────────────────┐
  <tr>  ◄────────────────────────────┘
    <td> description and capture data </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My question is : how can I insert those two tags by calling a JS function? I wish I could do something like this :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <video>s </td>

<script>
if ( mobile() ) write "</tr>
                       <tr>";
</script>

    <td> description and capture data </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`mobile()` is the JS function that returns TRUE if device is mobile.

I found two answers about manipulating the DOM (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333557/3298930 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27525472/3298930) but I couldn't make it work, here it is :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="my_td"> <video>s </td>

<script>
if ( mobile() ) $("#my_td").append("</tr><tr>");
</script>

    <td> description and capture data </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Consider solving this using CSS rather than Javascript. If you want to use Bootstrap you could utilize their grid system and use columns that collapse on smaller viewports: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553496/3298930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do only on initial load

```js
function isMobile() {
    return true; // or false
}

$(function () {

    if (isMobile()) {
        $td = $('#tbl').find('#row1_item2').detach();
        $a = $('#row1').after(`<tr id="row2"></tr>`);

        $('#row2').append($td);
    }

    $('#row1_item2').css('display', 'table-row');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
    <tr id="row1">
        <td id="row1_item1">a</td>
        <td id="row1_item2" style="display: none;">b</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```